# How to update an image that will not return to its default state after switching between view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
```

currently this image is set too "myfirstimage" in the attributes inspector

```
    @IBAction func changeimage(_ sender: Any) {
        image1.image = UIImage(named: "mysecondimage")
    }
```

When I click the `changeimage` button, the image changes. However, as soon as I go to a different view controller and come back, the image is back to "myfirstimage". How do I make the change to "mysecondimage" permanent despite moving in and out of other views?

Comment: where are you setting image1 to first image?

Comment: How do you "come back"? That's the problem so you need to explain in detail.

Comment: In the attributes inspector of Xcode, after clicking on the UIimage within storyboard, where it says 'image view' + image

Comment: I have a button that pushes to a different viewcontroller and then a button on that controller to come back.

Comment: @NickSenior When you "come back" are you instantiating another instance of `ViewController1` through your segue? Your image should stay the same unless you are reloading the entire VC.

Comment: No, I am going to viewcontroller2, then coming back to viewcontroller1

Comment: Show the code you use or explain the "come back" process. Are you using a navigation controller? An unwind segue? Dismissing a modal presentation?

Comment: I have just 'control click and dragged' from a button to a new view controller and clicked Action Segue - Show, all from the storyboard.

Comment: So you are presenting a new instance of the view controller

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit

struct Globalvariable {
static var setimage = 0
}

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
 inspector

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Globalvariable.setimage == 0 {
        image1.image = UIImage(named: "myfirstimage")
        }

        else {
        image1.image = UIImage(named: "mysecondimage")
            }

    @IBAction func changeimage(_ sender: Any) {

    image1.image = UIImage(named: "mysecondimage")
    Globalvariable.setimage = 1
    }
```

I was able to work it out by creating a variable in a structure outside of the class and adding the images into viewDidLoad connected to the Globalvariable. Not sure if this was the best way to go, but it is working.

Comment: Since you are not correctly using an unwind segue you are creating an ever-deeper list of view controllers and unnecessarily using memory